# Remove extra white space with str_replace

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace, space

The title and the code is pretty much self explanatory...

but just to clarify more...

I want to stay with a single space between each word inside `$myString` (and remove bad words)...

I prefer to stay in single line if possible...

```
$myString = 'There    will      be     no   extra    space       here !!!';

str_replace(array("bad words","another bad words","\s+"), '', $myString);
```

I'm expecting to get :

```
There will be no extra space here !!!
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$myString =     preg_replace('/\s\s*/', ' ',$myString);
```

Comment: Yes I know that trick but I was wondering if it's possible to do it inside : str_replace(array("bad words","another bad words","\s+{2}"), '', $myString);

Answer (score 2):

#### View Demo <kbd>[**Live**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xhlIdB)</kbd>

**`str_replace`** replaces a specific occurrence of a string. and in your case you have to remove only white space not need to replace so **`preg_replace`** is best suit for your case.

To remove all unwanted white space you just do as such,

#### Code

```
<?php

$myString = 'There    will      be     no   extra    space       here !!!';
echo str_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$myString);

?>
```

**`str_replace`** and **`preg_replace`** both produce same result. you can see on **[here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9mtLb3)**

#### Result

```
There will be no extra space here !!!
```

Comment: Yes I know that trick but I was wondering if it's possible to do it inside str_replace (without using another extra line)...

Answer (score 1):

```
print (preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $myString));
```

Comment: Yes I know that trick but I was wondering if it's possible to do it inside str_replace (without using another extra line)...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
$myString = 'There    will      be     no   extra    space       here !!!';

str_replace(array("bad words","another bad words","\s\s"), array("","", " "), $myString);
```

You can use an array in the $replace param, which indexed elements relace those of the $search param.

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```